# Can we calculate $\sin( (e+\pi )^{100} ) $ without a calculator supporting high-precision-calculations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, taylor-expansion

This problem is an exercise from *Hazrat: Mathematica - a problem centered* and it is originally focused to training Mathematica-based computation with large precision. But I believe that there exist a "pure-math" solution, without using a hard computational power.

Comment: And it's not my homework ;)

Comment: To enumerate is to name one by one in a list.  For example, to enumerate the prime numbers is to say 2, 3, 5, 7, and so on.  What does it mean to enumerate an expression?

Comment: I don't think that there will be an easy expression. If it were an integer plus $\pi$ to the 100, then one might think of exploiting the periodicity but the $e$ makes things quite complicated.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: I think you know what he wants. The OP simply wants to know if there is an easy paper pencil way to evaluate this expression. BTW why are people voting down, without giving any explanation?

Comment: @ MrYouMath Yes ;)
For example, $ Sin((1+π)^{100}) $ is easier

Comment: @SlepeckyMamut: Even that is not trivial.

Comment: @MrYouMath The problem is that "homework question" should be avoided, so the OP should "show some effort" and/or "context" and "where he/she got stuck". But this approach sometimes leads to downvotes which are at least debateable.

Comment: @Peter How do people infer that this is a homework question? He said that it is a Mathematica exercise but he wants to know if there is a non-numerical method to get the result.

Comment: @MrYouMath Here, this should be obvious, but downvotes without reason often happen here. I just upvoted as well because I think such questions are useful, even if the answer is simply "no, we cannot do that".

Comment: @SlepeckyMamut Try it for $\sin((1+\pi)^2)$ and I think you will find that you are mistaken about how easy it is.

Comment: There is a story in [Richard Feynman's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman) memoirs about how he claimed to be able to mentally solve, in one minute, to within 10% accuracy, any problem that could be stated in ten seconds.  He did solve many such problems, but one day he brought his boast to a colleague who instantly defeated him by asking for $\tan(10^{100})$.  Feynman wrote: “I was sunk: you have to divide by pi to 100 decimal places! It was hopeless.” Your problem is a little easier in some ways, because the argument is “only” 78 digits . But the basic trouble is the same.

Comment: @MrYouMath But upvotes "to heaven" happen even more often and considering the priviliges resulting from that this is worse than "undeserved" downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

It seems very unlikely. Computing the sin of very large numbers is notoriously difficult, because argument reduction needs high-precision values of $\pi$. In your example, $(e+\pi )^{100} \approx 6 \cdot 10^{76}$.

Here is a floating-point computation with varying precision in the values of $e$ and $\pi$. The Mathematica result is given at the end.

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
digits & values\\
1 & 0.57692985693159 \\
2 & 0.57692985693159 \\
3 & 0.55158252285758 \\
4 & 0.88100021612641 \\
5 & 0.97844910761855 \\
6 & -0.96707941886833 \\
7 & -0.038694543411024 \\
8 & -0.59146520442434 \\
9 & -0.23064541758482 \\
10 & 0.6405009829424 \\
11 & -0.96773597526623 \\
12 & 0.48727942317115 \\
13 & 0.8136210969004 \\
14 & 0.58164216885578 \\
15 & 0.15644468835041 \\
16 & 0.69937776018788 \\
17 & 0.88283169106665 \\
\infty & 0.7997513759791 \\\end{array}
$$

Comment: What does "digits" mean here? The precision in e and pi, before adding and raising it to the power 100?

Comment: @TMM, yes, exactly. The rest is done in full double precision.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665418/standard-for-the-sine-of-very-large-numbers.